# Is there any way of sending an email to Azure Service principal through an Azure function?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

We are exploring Graph API, but couldn't find any code for sending emails to a service principal. Does anyone have any articles or helpful code? Thanks

Comment: What is the use case for sending an email to a service principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Principals have no email. But if you want to send an email to user mailbox you can use Graph API described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0. Don't forget to properly auth. before you send an email and make sure you have correct API permissions to send emails: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions